# ng-upload not working on Firefox 26 and Chrome 31

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using the **directive ng-upload** from [here](https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload).
[This is](https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload/blob/fe2b115462355e68cf8121879c1d5a4029cdec4e/ng-upload.js) the version that I am using.

On "Chrome 32 Aura" the directive is working great, but:

- On Chrome 31 I am getting the error **"Response is not a valid JSON"** when I try to save the form.
- On Firefox 26 I am getting the same error but when the screen is initialized.

**The error cames from the line #191.** I cannot find a way to make it work, I tried with differents JSON parsers, validating the content, but is still failling.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form ng-upload="uploadComplete(content)" upload-options-before-submit="beforeLoading(form)" name="form" action="/v1/themes"> 
   <div class="form-group theme-middleContainer">
    <label for="logoType">Logotype</label>
    <div class="input-group theme-logotypeContainer">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img class="organization-image" ng-src="{{imageSrc}}" ng-hide="imageSrc==undefined"/>
      </div>
      <div class="uploader-container">
        <input class="form-control btn btn-inverse upload-input" type="file" id="logoType" name="logoType" accept="image/png" ng-model="theme.logoType" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="error" ng-show="invalidImageExtension">Please select file in <b>png</b> format.</div>
    <div class="error" ng-show="form.logoType.$error.required && submitted">Please select a logo.</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here are my angular methods:

```
$scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
   $scope.$apply(function () { $scope.theme.logoType = args.file; });
});

$scope.beforeLoading = function(form){
   $scope.submitted = true;
   return !(form.$invalid);
};

$scope.uploadComplete = function (content) {
   $scope.submitted = false;
   if ( _.isObject(content)) {
      $location.path("/home");
   }else{
      $scope.hasError = true;
      $scope.errorMessage = content;
   }
};
```

BTW: I am using node.js on the backend. On Chrome 31 I see the image saved on mongoDB, I see the correct content response but the json error is still there.

Does anyone find a workaround or has experimented the same issue?